# Merge two HTML table cells

Tags: html, html-table

I'm creating a table in HTML and I'd like to have my top cell be the width of two. Here's a rough drawing:

```
__________________________________________
|                HEADER                  |
|                                        |
==========================================
|                  ||                    |
|     CONTENT      ||       CONTENT      |
|                  ||                    |
------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in HTML?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Set the `colspan` attribute to 2.

...but [please don't use tables for layout](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/).

Comment: And rowspan for merging vertically.

Answer (score 109):

Add an attribute [`colspan`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#adef-colspan) (abbriviation for 'column span') in your top cell (`<td>`) and set its value to 2.
Your table should resembles the following;

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan = "2">
            <!-- Merged Columns -->
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Column 1 -->
        </td>

        <td>
            <!-- Column 2 -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**See also**
     [W3 official docs on HTML Tables](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html)

Comment: Demo of this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/fky8xvu0/

Answer (score 3):

Use [colspan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan) for do this:

```
 <td colspan="3">PUR mix up column</td>
```