# Table row span cell span

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is an assignment I need help with. I hate tables as is, but this is what it says:

> "The first row in each table consists of one table cell which spans two columns that contain the real estate listing name. The second row in each table consists of two table cells."

My code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <h3>TEST</h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <th rowspan="2"></th>
    <td>Something here !</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Just wanted to verify if I did this correctly? Here's the full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/4jzUc/

also, it's supposed to look like this: http://screencloud.net/v/aA5Y

Comment: Looks like homework. If it is, tell your teacher that using `<table/>` for layout is bullsh** and he is absolutely not supposed to teach you. You can refer to my user profile if you want to. I'd like to discuss this topic anytime... we'll have fun! ;-)

Comment: yeah, I hate tables man. But it's useful when PHP is enact. but I understand what u mean !

Comment: tables are good for 'um, tabular data!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge two HTML table cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342336/merge-two-html-table-cells)

Answer (score 2):

You want to span the column, not the row (`colspan` vs `rowspan`). I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th colspan="2">
           Title
       </th>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>First cell</td>
    </tr>                       
    <tr>
       <td>Second cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, your markup is not correct. It does not even comply with the HTML table model, as you can see by using http://validator.nu on your document with `<!doctype html>` slapped at the start. Still less it does do what the assignment calls for.

The assignment as such is very simple: you just a table with two rows and two columns, just so that the first row has only one cell, which spans two columns:

```
<table>
  <tr><td colspan=2>Real estate name
  <tr><td>A table cell <td>Another table cell
</table>
```

You could use `th` instead of the first `td`, since it is kind of a header cell, but beware then that this makes its content bold and centered by default (you can override this is in CSS).

As per the “supposed to look like” link, it seems that you are supposed to put an `img` element only in the first cell of the second row, and the second cell there contains text and a `ul` element. And a little bit of CSS too. Note that for this output, you will need to align the second row vertically to the top (using the HTML `valign` attribute or the CSS `vertical-align` property).

Answer (score -1):

correct code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>
           <h3>TEST</h3>
       </th>
       <th rowspan="2">RowSpan2!</th>   
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Something here !</td>
   </tr>                       
   <tr>
       <td>Something Else !</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not correct: "The first row in each table consists of one table cell which spans two columns"