# Table with 3 headers but two columns

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to do this type of table using HTML / CSS?

```
Header1 | Header2 | Header 3
--------+---------+----------
0       | 1  asdasdasdasd 7
2       | 5  asdasdasdasd 3
9       | 7  asdasdasdasd 2
```

Comment: html attribute colspan

Comment: how come this has so many upvotes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two HTML table cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342336/merge-two-html-table-cells)

Answer (score 2):

If you have `<table>` markup then `<td colspan=2>` will help you. 
If you want this with `<div>`s and so with pure CSS then you will need so called [grid systems](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 2):

By using `colspan` you can make cells span multiple columns.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td colspan="2">1 asdasdasdasd 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td colspan="2">5 asdasdasdasd 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td colspan="2">7 asdasdasdasd 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Forgive the edit, but a `row` can always span multiple columns; it's the `<td>` element that needs to span multiple columns with the `colspan` attribute. :)