# how to merge the row of the table using css?

Tags: html, css

ok so i have do the a table . The problem i facing is i want to know how to merge the row of my table ... anyone can help me or teach me on how to merge the row of my table ?? for example if my row1 and row2 below want to merge as one row, how do i merge it ? would be happy if someone can help me :) [ ps : can i merge the table by writing something in the style there ?? if can then how ??
below is my code :]

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
  .Table
  {
    display: table;
  }
  .Title
  {
    display: table-caption;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
}
.Heading
{
    display: table-row;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.Row
{
    display: table-row;
}
.Cell
{
    display: table-cell;
    border: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
</style>
 <body>

 <div class="Table">
  <div class="Title">
    <p>This is a Table</p>
</div>
<div class="Heading">
    <div class="Cell">
        <p>Heading 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Cell">
        <p>Heading 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Cell">
        <p>Heading 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Row">
    <div class="Cell">
        <p>Row 1 Column 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Cell">
        <p>Row 1 Column 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Cell">
        <p>Row 1 Column 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Row">
    <div class="Cell">
        <p>Row 2 Column 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Cell">
        <p>Row 2 Column 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Cell">
        <p>Row 2 Column 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two HTML table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342336/merge-two-html-table-cells)

Answer (score 1):

use rowspan attribute on the `<td>` tag. for example. use `<td rowspan="2">this row is two rows merged</td>` you could find more resource about this in https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_td_rowspan.asp