# How can I create these type of tables in html

Tags: html, css, tabular

How  can I create these type of tables in html? The green one is the main header and there are some main header having subheaders.
I have tried many solutions, but I can't figure out how it will work.

[image]

Comment: You need to use rowspan and colspan

Comment: What have you tried so far to create such a table in html?

Comment: Or [merge two html table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342336/merge-two-html-table-cells)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is example of using rowspan and colspan.

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">header</th>
            <th rowspan="2">header</th>
            <th colspan="4">header</th>
            <th rowspan="2">header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>subheader</th>
            <th>subheader</th>
        
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Refer [this](https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/) for more information